# Android FirebaseVisionImage Camera orientation

Tags: android, firebase, android-camera, ocr, firebase-mlkit

I am writing an app that requires the Firebase ml kit to read text (FirebaseVisionImage) and i am using this [Google Firebase Page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text) for instructions.

However I am having issues using the `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` Intent.  When i run the app, take a photo and then try and process the image i mostly get back null from the text recogniser.  I believe this is due to the orientation not being provided or that on Android the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE is only using the thumbnail?

When it does (kind of) work (not return null) the text recogniser is not recognising any of the text and instead may return just a few characters.  It is probably worth noting that i have developed a prototype of this same app on iOS and it is working fine.  My take away from this is that it is how the image is captured and returned between the two platforms.  On iOS i call a function to get the image orientation and parse that in to the FirebaseVision function.

The documentation also uses CameraX in some of its examples however i am not using this as it seems to still be in alpha stage of development.

Have i missed something? How do i get the orientation?

```
private fun openCamera() {
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, R.string.app_name)
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Capturing Photo!")

    image_uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

    //camera intent
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //process captured image

        //image_uri
        Log.d(TAG, "$image_uri")

        val bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, image_uri)

        val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bmp)
        val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().onDeviceTextRecognizer

        val result = detector.processImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { firebaseVisionText ->
                // Task completed successfully
                // ...

                Log.d(TAG, "Process complete -> ${firebaseVisionText.text}")

                val resultText = firebaseVisionText.text
                Log.d(TAG, "$resultText")

            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.d(TAG, "Process failed $e")
            }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult -> resultCode: $resultCode")
    }
}
```